# Angular map HttpClient.Post

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

So I finally decided to catch up with the times and migrate some old angular `Http` stuff to `HttpClient`.

The app used to run on a bunch of Promise based code, which has since been removed (mostly). 
My old Promise function looked something like this:

```
public getUser(profileId: number): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.post("/api/url", postObject, HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions());
    .map(u => new User(u))
    .catch(this.handleError)
    .toPromise();
}
```

My new HttpClient function is much nicer:

```
public getUser(profileId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post("/api/url", postObject, HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions());
}
```

But what I don't like currently is that in **each** subscription to this, I now have to map the data to an instance of User...

```
service.getUser(1).subscribe(data => {
    data = new User(data);
});
```

*This is the simplest `.map` which I have, some post methods actually return a rather complex object which map to many new object instances.*

I see with `HttpClient.get` you can Type assert the response, can I do something like this with `.post` so that I don't have to map the data to a new User in each of the subscriptions?

**Note:** Eventually I will migrate this again to a better architecture where you actually subscribe to a User variable, but for now I just want to implement HttpClient.

Comment: `can I do something like this with .post so that I don't have to map the data to a new User in each of the subscriptions` <= Yes, the exact same generic to specify the return type is available for `post` and also `put`. It will not convert automatically to an object but you can specify an interface for the returned data. Alternatively you can chain `map` in the service like you did previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`can I do something like this with .post so that I don't have to map the data to a new User in each of the subscriptions` <= Yes, the exact same generic to specify the return type is available for `post` and also `put`. It will not convert automatically to an object but you can specify an interface for the returned data. Alternatively you can chain `map` in the service like you did previously but I recommend you use the [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

---

Example using [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) to mimic what you had in your previous code.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

public getUser(profileId: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post("/api/url", postObject, HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions())
        .pipe(map(data => new User(data)));
}
```

---

Example where `User` is nothing more than an interface with properties.

If the data itself is json representative of an interface that has properties you can convert it directly.

```
export interface User {
  userId: number;
  name: string;
}


public getUser(profileId: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>("/api/url", postObject, HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions());
}
```

Comment: I'm conflicted on whether this answer makes me happy, or infuriated because I swear that I tried `.post<User>` and it wasn't working.... Can confirm that it works..... :( - thankyou.

Comment: The `.pipe` method on the other hand is excellent to know about and I will certainly need to implement that later on.

Comment: @Zze - I added a link to the rxjs page about pipeable operators, these provide more insight as to how to use them.

Comment: @Zze - I added the import statement. The only requirement is that you are using  RxJs version  5.5 or later.

Comment: How does `map(data)` handle this process if data is an array and not an object? - How do I ... `map(data => { return data.map( ele => new Thing(ele)); }` to return an `Array<Thing>`.

Comment: @Zze - Your code sample looks fine, what is wrong with it? Did you change the signature on the method to return an observable of `Thing[]` instead of just `Thing` maybe?

Comment: I made a second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562160/rxjs-map-to-an-array-of-type - I would appreciate it if you could please have a glance at it.

Answer (score 2):

If you import your User class in the service, you can map it back to a `User` object by add `<User>` after the `post` and before the `()`

```
public getUser(profileId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<User>("/api/url", postObject, HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions());
}
```