# Angular HttpClient - rxjs map - to an array of Type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following `HttpClient.post` call which return an array of Objects.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

public getArray(profileId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post("/api/url", postObject, HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions())
        .pipe(map(data => { 
          console.log(data); // logs (2) [{…}, {…}]
          return data;
        }));
}
```

I need to Instantiate an Array of objects. I can't just type assert because I need the `Thing` constructor to parse some `json` and other.

Essentially what I want to do is:

```
.pipe(map(data => { 
      console.log(data); // logs (2) [{…}, {…}]
      return data.map(v => new Thing(v));
    }));
```

However I can't (to my knowledge) because `data` is of Type `ArrayBuffer` and is not iterable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How is the data actually sent from the server? Is it `json` or something else? If it is `json` try specifying that in the `HttpClient`'s call ([see documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)) using `responseType:'json'` in the `options` parameter.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

public getArray(profileId: number): Observable<Thing[]> {
    var options = HttpSettings.GetDefaultHttpRequestOptions();
    options.responseType = 'json';

    return this.http.post("/api/url", postObject, options)
        .pipe(map(data => data.map(v => new Thing(v))));
}
```

Comment: could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854143/unable-to-compile-a-code-when-converted-into-a-function I think I am facing similar issue but my code compiles under certain conditions and doesn't under some. The issue is around `ArrayBuffer` but I don't know why it compiles sometimes.