# unable to compile a code when converted into a function

Tags: typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I have the following piece of code which works correctly.

```
  public createData(data:Data):Observable<any>{
    console.log('contacting server at '+this.API_URL +this.NEW_DATA_URL +" with data "+data+ " with httpOptions "+httpOptions.withCredentials + ","+httpOptions.headers );

let newData = new Data(data)    
    let body = JSON.stringify(newQuestion); 
//I WANT TO MOVE THE CODE BELOW INTO A FUNCTION BUT AM GETTING COMPILATION ERROR
    this.loaderService.show();
    return this.http.post(this.NEW_QUESTION_URL,body,httpOptions)
      .pipe(tap(response => { 
        let httpEvent = <HttpEvent<any>>response;
        if(httpEvent.type === HttpEventType.Response)
        {
          console.log('response from backend service:', response);

          return result;
        }
        else {
          console.log("not an http response")
          return response;
        }
      })
      ,catchError(this.handleError)
        ,finalize(()=> this.loaderService.hide())); //error handler if Observable fails

  }
```

As I can reuse some part of the code, I thought to create a function but now I am getting compilation errors. I am unable to find out what is the mistake.

The new function is

```
private sendMessage(url:string, body:any,httpOptions:any){
    this.loaderService.show();
    return this.http.post(url,body,httpOptions)
      .pipe(tap(response => { 

          let httpEvent = <HttpEvent<any>>response; //ERROR HERE - 'ArrayBuffer' cannot be converted to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
          if(httpEvent.type === HttpEventType.Response)
          {
            console.log('response from backend service:', response);

            let result = <HttpResponse<any>>response;

            return result;
          }
          else {
            console.log("not an http response")
            return response;
          }
        })
        ,catchError(this.handleError)
        ,finalize(()=> this.loaderService.hide())); //error handler if Observable fails
    }
```

ERROR is 
`ERROR in src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(264,27): error TS2352:` `Type 'ArrayBuffer' cannot be converted to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.`
`Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not comparable to type 'HttpUserEvent<any>'.`
`Property 'type' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.`

`http.post` has several overloaded methods and one of them return Observable - angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post. How do I make Angular use the overloaded version which returns `Observable<T>`? I changed the code and added `responseType:'json'` but that didnt work either

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  withCredentials: true, 
observe: 'response' as 'response', 
  responseType: 'json' 
};


let observable:Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = this.http.post(url,body,httpOptions)
    return observable.pipe(tap((httpEvent:HttpEvent<any>) => {....}
```

The errors I am seeing are

```
ERROR in src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(80,71): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(111,52): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(195,73): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(215,72): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(250,54): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(290,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
    Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'HttpUserEvent<any>'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(296,59): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'response'. Did you mean 'Response'?
```

Why does making a separate function of a working code makes it non-compilable? What is my mistake?

Comment: It looks like `response` is getting a different type in the two versions of the code.  This is presumably a consequence of the type of one of the things passed in up to that point: `this.http`, `url`, `body`, or `httpOptions`.  It's hard for me to debug without knowing the type of `this.http`.  But you can debug by yourself by hovering over each function call to see which overload is being chosen and the resulting return type.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct it seems. `post` has several overloaded methods and one of them return `Observable<ArrayBuffer>` - https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post . I'll debug further and update this thread. If it works, happy to accept your comment as answer

Comment: sorry, I have not been able to figure this out :(. Updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve it but now I am left with more questions than answers. Would appreciate if someone could explain the behaviour to me.

I was using the following `httpOptions` object

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),

withCredentials: true, 
observe: 'response' as 'response', 

};
```

as was using it as follows in some places in the code.

```
 return this.http.post(this.SIGNUP_USER_URL,body,httpOptions)
```

This worked.

Then I thought of changing the `http.post` into a function `sendMessage` (as explained in the question) and replaced it in only once place (remember I am using `this.http.post` in several places so wanted to try it at one place to begin with). I noticed that using `httpOptions` made `post` return `Observable<ArrayBuffer>`.

Doubt 1 - why?

Then I changed `httpOptions` to

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),

withCredentials: true, 
observe: 'response' as 'response', 
responseType:'json'  
};
```

It started giving me errors at places where I am using `http.post` directly (without `sendMessage`. The error was

```
ERROR in src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(81,71): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(112,52): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(196,73): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(216,72): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(251,54): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; withCredentials: boolean; observe: "response"; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
src/app/web-to-backend-interface.service.ts(291,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
    Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'HttpUserEvent<any>'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.
```

So I removed `responseType:'json'` from `httpOptions` and added an explicit object in `this.http.post` in my `sendMessage` which worked!

```
private sendMessage(url:string, body:any,httpOptions){
  ...
    let observable:Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = this.http.post(url,body,{
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
          withCredentials: true,
          observe: 'events',
          responseType: 'json'
        })
...
}
```

there seem to be relationship between observe and responseType. Eg observe=body and responseType=text means that post should observe (look in) the body, interpret it as text and return Observable. But I wonder why I just couldn't change `httpOptions`

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer why you'd be getting a TS error now when you weren't before, I can advise you how to get rid of it (assuming the code was previously working before you refactored it). If you give `response` a type on declaration, then it won't get an assumed type that you have to try and map:

```
.pipe(tap((response: HttpEvent<any>) => { 

      let httpEvent = response; // No need for type-casting here anymore.
```

Comment: sorry,that didn't work. I was able to solve the issue but still have doubts. You may look at my answer